# Javascript error on iterating through two arrays for hit detection

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, canvas, ecmascript-6

I'm making a small html5 canvas game in pure JS (with the standards of Ecmascript 6).
So far, everything went well, but now I am stuck on a recurring TypeError (**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'position' of undefined**).

This happens every so often, when the game checks for collisions between objects inside two arrays (to be more specific: collision detection between Bullets and Enemies).

Mostly, my collision detection function works fine. When I think I've fixed the issue, it just happens again, after a while.

This is my code:

```
const collisionCheckBulletEnemy = () => {

    for(let i = bullets.length -1; i >= 0; i--){
        for(let j = enemies.length -1; j >= 0; j--){

            if(collisionCheck(bullets[i], enemies[j], 10, 10)){

                bullets.splice(i, 1);
                enemies.splice(j, 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the collision detection function:

```
const collisionCheck = (a, b, marginA, marginB) => {
    // margins can be added to make things a little easier/harder on the user
    if(!marginA){
        marginA = 0;
    }
    if(!marginB){
        marginB = 0;
    }

    return !(
        a.position.x - marginA > b.position.x + b.width + marginB ||
        a.position.x + a.width + marginA < b.position.x - marginB ||
        a.position.y - marginA > b.position.y + b.height + marginB ||
        a.position.y + a.height + marginA < b.position.y - marginB
    );
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger to figure out what is `undefined`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because sometimes either the parameter `a` or `b` is passed into the function even though it's just an `undefined` value. Trying to do `undefined.position` will cause your type error.

The simple, hacky solution is simply putting a condition at the top:

```
if (!a || !b) {
  return 0; // or whatever your default value is supposed to be
};
```

The real, better solution is figuring out why `bullets` and `enemies` contain some undefined values.

After reading your code I think this is the answer:

if this condition passes when `i = bullets.length - 1`:

```
if(collisionCheck(bullets[i], enemies[j], 10, 10)) {
  bullets.splice(i, 1);
  enemies.splice(j, 1);
}
```

specifically this part `bullets.splice(i, 1);` you shorten your array by 1, but you never decrement `i`.

So if `bullets[i]` was the very last element in your array now `bullets[i]` is `undefined` because javascript doesn't throw an error like `indexOutOfBounds`.

Now you begin to see that the huge flaw in your code is that it doesn't stop looping when a bullet is removed from the array, and that you only noticed when it was the very last index. Even if it isn't the very last index, it will continue to loop for another bullet which doesn't seem like your intention.

Instead you should break out of the loop since if are destroying your bullet when it hits, you shouldn't keep checking collisions for that same bullet:

```
if(collisionCheck(bullets[i], enemies[j], 10, 10)) {
  bullets.splice(i, 1);
  enemies.splice(j, 1);
  break;
}
```